# Serialize a single Related Field in Django

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

In my Django application I am getting data from seriallizer like the following:

```
{
        "id": 98,
        "flows": [
            {
                "id": 99,
                "asked_quantity": 14,
                "alloted_quantity": 14,
                "flow": 1,
                "kit": 1                    #this
            }
        ],
        "transaction_no": 2317,
        "dispatch_date": "2020-07-27T04:42:46.356000Z",
        "is_delivered": false,
        "model": "Rent",
        "driver_name": "__________",
        "driver_number": "__________",
        "lr_number": 0,
        "vehicle_number": "__________",
        "freight_charges": 0,
        "vehicle_type": "Part Load",
        "expected_delivery": "2020-07-27T04:42:46.356000Z",
        "remarks": "0",
        "send_from_warehouse": 1,            #this
        "sales_order": 98,
        "transport_by": 4,
        "owner": 2
    },
```

Where `Flows` is a manytomany connected field, I just want to Expand the `kit` from flows and `send_from_warehouse` but when I increase the depth all the related fields gets expanded.

Here's how I tried doing this :

```
class KSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Kit
        fields = "__all__"


class WSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Warehouse
        fields = "__all__"


class AFSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    kit = KSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = AllotmentFlow
        fields = "__all__"


class AReportSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    flows = AFSerializer(many=True)
    send_from_warehouse = serializers.RelatedField(source='warehouse.pk', read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Allotment
        fields = "__all__"
```

But I got the error that 'kits`is not serializable and`send_from_warehouse` vanishes from the JSON.
Please explain why did that happen and what's the right way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class AFSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = AllotmentFlow
        fields = "__all__"


class AReportSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    flows = AFSerializer(many=True)
    send_from_warehouse = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
    read_only=True,
    slug_field='send_from_warehouse'
 )

    class Meta:
        model = Allotment
        fields = "__all__"
```

I guess this is what you are looking for.

Comment: it gives the error with `many=True` but with false it returns the same value as before... `        "send_from_warehouse": 1,`  I just want the name of Warehouse instead of the `pk`

Comment: It works well, thanks but as per the other part of the question, how should I expand `"kit": 1     #this` without increasing the depth ?

Comment: try to define KitSerializer in your AReportSerializer and check. and keep depth = 1

Comment: But shouldn't the Kit serializer be defined in the `AFSerializer` instead of `AReportSerializer` ?

Comment: if you define it there it will give all the details as you are getting now